# How to set a legent without points and duplicate with in the plot?

Tags: gnuplot, legend

I would like only the title in the legent without point. 
When I plot yerrorbar, there is an error:

```
duplicated or contradicting arguments in plot options
```

How to rewrite it?

```
set key tc variable
plot 'file.txt' with points pt 7 title "A" with yerrorbar
```

If something is missing in my question, let me know please.

Comment: Try `plot 'file.txt' with yerrorbar title "A" `.

Comment: It works, but how to define I want points and pt 7?  There is an error because of `with` twice

Answer (score 1):

In recent gnuplot versions there is a separate option `keyentry` (introduced in version 5.2.6).

The documentation says

```
gnuplot> help keyentry
 Normally each plot autogenerates a single line entry in the key.  If you need
 more control over what appears in the key you can use the `keyentry` keyword
 in the `plot` or `splot` command to insert extra lines.  Instead of providing
 a filename or function to plot, use `keyentry` as a placeholder followed by
 plot style information (used to generate a key symbol) and a title.
```

Example

```
set key box width 3
plot 'file.txt' with points pt 7 notitle, keyentry title "Some Title"
```

[image]

In older gnuplot versions a work-around is to plot some function that lies entirely outside the plot and give it the desired title.  This may generate warning messages such as "all points out of range" but it does place the title in the key. Example below. Note that the pointtype is given as an empty string.

```
set yrange [0:*]
plot 'file.txt' with points pt 7 notitle,  -1 with points pt '' title "Some Title"
```